# How to convert this Oracle query to Linq?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Can anyone help me out converting this query to Linq? as I am a newbie to linq and finding hard to convert this. Thanks.

```
SELECT 
       a.gb,
       b.gb,
       SUM(a.amnt) amnt,
       SUM(b.amnt) anotheramount
FROM table1 a
LEFT JOIN table2 b ON a.gb = b.gb
WHERE 
       a.filter1 = 'value1' AND 
       b.filter2 = 'value2'
GROUP BY a.gb,b.gb;
```

Comment: You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] and also [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN b ... WHERE b.filter2 = 'value2'` :(

Comment: you can also use following tool to convert SQL to LINQ http://www.sqltolinq.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't test this but the solution should be something like this. please try to find if you can use different names in groupby.

```
table1.Join(table2, a => a.gb, b => b.gb, (a, b) => new { table1 = a, table2 = b }).Where(a => a.table1.id > 1 && a.table2.id > 1).GroupBy(s => new { s.table1.gb, s.table2.gb})
        .Select(g => new { amnt = g.Sum(x => x.table1.amnt), anotheramount = g.Sum(x => x.table2.amnt), gba = g.Key.gb, gbb = g.Key.id }); ;
```

Comment: Join lambda method results in `INNER JOIN`, you need to use `GroupJoin` and `FirstOrDefault` In `Select` method